# How to create and populate a static 2D array of dynamically allocated objects

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic, static

I had a question about initializing a static 2D array of dynamic objects. I'm having many EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors and I believe the main issue is that I am not correctly initializing the array. Here is my code to declare an array and populate it. The array type is an abstract class, and I'm either populating the array with derived classes or nullptrs.

**Declaration:**

```
Creature* grid[SIZE_X][SIZE_Y];
```

**Populating:**

```
void populateGrid(Creature* grid[SIZE_X][SIZE_Y], string fileName)
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open(fileName);

    string line = "";
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(getline(file, line))
    {
        for(char x : line)
        {
            switch (x)
            {
            case 'B':
                grid[i][j] = new Beetle();
                break;
            case 'a':
                grid[i][j] = new Ant();
                break;
            default:
                grid[i][j] = nullptr;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        j++;
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

I was just wondering if I'm currently initializing a 2D static array with dynamic objects? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks so much.

This is the file that I'm reading from:

```
   aaa    
 B  aa    
 B   a    
 B    aaa 
      aaa 
a     aaa 
a         
a   aaaa  
    aaaa
```

Comment: please post a [mcve].

Comment: are you sure that there are no more than `SIZE_Y` lines and no more than `SIZE_X` entries per line in the file?

Comment: You might be creating the array in the stack or in static storage and blowing up the size of it. I'd rather create in the heap with `std::vector< std::vector<Creature> >`.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher When debugging, I would get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when dynamically casting. It would also be a random spot within the array, such as i: 1, j: 3.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I added the file from which I'm reading from. As far as I know I am creating the array with proper boundaries. I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in the middle of the array, far from any boundaries.

Comment: there arent same number of characters in every line

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I'm also reading for ' '

Comment: If this array of arrays is as disparate as you show, you could just go jagged with an unordered map of index to unordered map of index to unique_ptr of covariant creature derivations, which may be a better alternative, especially for large dimensions.